# Laravel 5.4 Model Properties and Methods Inheritance

Tags: php, laravel, inheritance, eloquent, laravel-5.4

The main model is **BaseMonster**, with all the basic informations of a monster (stats, monster type, etc) that will be inherited by child classes.

At the moment, I have two child classes named **WildMonster** and **PlayerMonster**, related to **BaseMonster** with a one to many relationship (from BaseMonster side).

My main goal is to be able to **inherit attributes like stats, names and images and all the related methods** from BaseMonster to other child monster classes.
This way i can **avoid db redundancy** for common attributes and at the same time **adjust various aspect of certain child monsters** just editing theirs parent BaseMonster record.
**Example**: "Kraken" monster has too high attack stat value. With a simple change to its **BaseMonster** record, all **WildMonster** and **PlayerMonster** instances related to "Kraken" are affected.

I want to **avoid code redundancy** too, for example making one rating() method in BaseMonster that will use all the actual stats (**along with stat bonuses and levels**) of the monster instance and that can be **used by any of the monster child classes**.

I tried accessing parent properties with Laravel accessors, and setting them to the **Eloquent base_monster relationship** stat, but this way i can't work with children attributes, **like level or health_bonus** to **adjust values accordingly**. (or at least i didn't find the right way).
I also tried setting **accessors from child side** with half a success, but anyway this mean i have to write the same accessors in all child classes and to make a huge mess if i want to change something.

How can I achieve something like this in laravel 5.4?

---

## Extract of attributes

---

***BaseMonster*** is the parent of the other monster classes and contains all the common attributes and methods needed in most of the occasions. **BaseMonsters are created by Game Admin** to manage things like stats and images and to generate new **WildMonster** to populate various **Dungeons**.

**BaseMonster** (extends **Model**)

- **name**
- **image**
- **health**
- **attack**
- **defense**
- **monster_type_id** (relationship with the MonsterType model)

---

***WildMonster*** is the monster encountered in dungeons or in other ways. Can "transform" to PlayerMonster if recruited.

**WildMonster** (extends **BaseMonster**)

- **name** (to customize name for special encounters)
- **level** (to adjust stats accordingly)
- **health_bonus** (there is a chance a monster has various stats bonuses)
- **attack_bonus**
- **defense_bonus**
- **base_monster_id** (relationship with the BaseMonster model)

---

***PlayerMonster*** is the monster recruited by the player after a battle.

**PlayerMonster** (extends **BaseMonster**)

- **name** (eventually customized by the player)
- **level**
- **health_bonus**
- **attack_bonus**
- **defense_bonus**
- **base_monster_id** (relationship with the BaseMonster model)

---

Comment: The answer is **"with  PHP"**. What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [Polymorphic Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) in Laravel. This way you can define a base model **BaseMonster** as requested. Following the example on the site:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BaseMonster extends Model
{

    public function monster_wild_or_player()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function monster_type()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\MonsterType');
    }
}

class PlayerMonster extends Model
{

    public function base_info()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\BaseMonster', 'monster_wild_or_player');
    }
}

class WildMonster extends Model
{

    public function base_info()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\BaseMonster', 'monster_wild_or_player');
    }
}
```

Comment: But won't this create redundancy? The example in the docs is talking about comments to posts or videos, and i think each comment is a different record in the DB. This way i will have id and type in the base_monsters table, instead of having them in the wild_monsters table or player_monsters table. I need a way to link one base_monster record to many WildMonsters or PlayerMonsters to avoid redundancy, so i think the correct way is having monsterable_id in the wild_monsters or player_monsters table, but i can't find the correct way to write that in monsters eloquent models.

Comment: I think at this point, a many to many polymorphic relationship is the way to go to assign a BaseMonster to multiple child classes, am I wrong? (but I guess I will have to check that a PlayerMonster or WildMonster has only one BaseMonster assigned this way)

Comment: That's a big one, I would solve it by creating 1 base and multiple derivatives also. Good luck

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, what do you mean by "1 base and multiple derivatives" ?

Comment: 1 BaseMonster object, multiple PlayerMonsters refferencing it. etc.